# Django: How to add a foreign key that references itself and also sets a field on the referenced object

Tags: django, django-models

Sorry for the terrible title.  I'm not even sure what I'm looking for.  Basically, I would like to create the following:

- Model comprised of Ethernet switch interfaces (ex. ge-0/0/1, po4096, etc.)
- Be able to connect Ethernet switch interfaces TOGETHER (so, a foreign key to its own model)

This is what I currently have:

```
class EthernetSwitchInterfaces(models.Model):
    """
    Represents interfaces on switches
    (ex. ge-0/0/1, ae1001, po1001, xe-1/1/1, eth1/101, etc.)
    """
    interface = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=False, help_text='Interface name (ex. xe-1/1/1, eth1/101, po1001, etc.)')
    switch = models.ForeignKey(EthernetSwitches, to_field='id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text='Switch')

    # Note the speed of that interface
    link_bandwidth_in_gbps = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, help_text='Total interface bandwidth in Gbps')

    # Account for port channel interfaces
    is_port_channel = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=False, help_text='Is this a port channel interface?')
    number_of_links = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=1, help_text='Number of links (if port channel)')

    switch_to_switch = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, help_text='Switch-to-switch connection', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.switch, self.interface)

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ('interface', 'switch',)
```

This *almost* works.  I create an interface, create a second interface, and set the second interface's *switch_to_switch* field to the original interface.  This works great except the original interface has a blank *switch_to_switch* value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've been stuck on this for a week now and it's driving me crazy.  Thanks!

Comment: To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`... i guess this handles the first part of your question

Comment: Yup, already have that part down (see switch_to_switch field in the code block above).

Comment: well done i didnt see it there